# How can I access the implicit event dispatcher of a bindable Flex object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

If I create an object like so:

```
class Foo {
    [Bindable] public var property: String;
}
```

The class `Foo` has an implicit event dispatcher to handle property change events. How can I access that without making `Foo` explicitly extend `EventDispatcher`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the `-keep` parameter to your compile line you will be able to see what it generates. But to explain it quickly you can just handle it like it would be a regular `EventDisaptcher`.

So in your main file you can paste this:

```
function callFirst(event:FlexEvent):void
{
   foo.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE,test);
   foo.property = 'something';
}

function test(E:Event):void
{
   trace (ObjectUtil.toString(E));
}
```

Will print out:

```
(mx.events::PropertyChangeEvent)#0
  bubbles = false
  cancelable = false
  currentTarget = (Foo)#1
    property = "something"
  eventPhase = 2
  kind = "update"
  newValue = "something"
  oldValue = (null)
  property = "property"
  source = (Foo)#1
  target = (Foo)#1
  type = "propertyChange"
```

Comment: I'm thinking from within Foo; I think what was confusing me was that the code completion support in Flash Builder will not propose dispatchEvent as a completion, but it compiles fine.  Okay, thanks!